# I want to know, directly related with Islam, the importance of the 1,001 Arabian Nights:

Tags: practical-islam, history, islamic-philosophy

***As-salamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh!***

***May the peace, mercy, and blessings of Allah be with you!***

What can we learn from 1,001 Arabian Nights about Islam, its importance, and any spiritual interpretation you can tell, based in the Holy Qu'ran within Islam, in synthesis, what can we learn by reading them, any prophetic meaning. I accept answers and also links for further study.

I was studying about Allah on the internet, and Holy Scriptures, and found your website.

It's my first question, I want to stick to the rules, so, please correct me, and maybe, I can edit the question, or rephrase, divide it on more questions.

I sincerely apologize for any mistake I may have made.

***Thank you: Praise is for Allah, and thanks to Allah!***

***Alhamdulillah***.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Islam

Comment: Basically this question as is is too broad as you may find in some details of the 1001 Arabian nights some indication that are relared to Islam, but the stories in general are not at all related to Islam, they are even rejected to some extent by some Muslims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no importance of Arabian Nights in Islam, it has no `spiritual interpretation` nor `prophetic meaning` in it, they are just fairy tales made by people for entertainment. You can learn nothing important about Islam from it, except references to Allah, Prophet, Solomon, Caliph, Jinn, while there are elements contrary to Islamic teachings in it like wine and music.

Comment: Since you are the experts in Islam in this community, to try not asking too much in other questions related to Arabian Nights, because of what you answered: in this same question, did Caliph Harun-al-Rashid existed? If he existed in your history annals, what did he did significantly to Islam, or how is he remembered, or estimated. I follow your rules not giving number ratings or saying how I appreciate your time and answers, etc.